# Removing brackets from a dataset

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have imported a dataset in R of 10 columns and 100 row. But in few columns there are brackets([]) and commas along with the values. How can i get rid of them?
As an instance, consider one of 4 columns and 2 rows.

```
V1  V2  V3   V4
3(  [4  ([5  8
(1  5   9   [10,
```

And what i want is

```
V1  V2   V3  V4
3   4     5   8
1   5     9   10
```

Comment: With `gsub`?  E.g.: `gsub("\\(|\\[","","(4[")`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `gsub`:

```
mydf[] <- lapply(mydf, function(x) gsub("[][(),]", "", x))
mydf
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  3  4  5  8
# 2  1  5  9 10
```

---

Instead of `lapply`, you can also use `as.matrix`:

```
mydf[] <- gsub("[][(),]", "", as.matrix(mydf))
mydf
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  3  4  5  8
# 2  1  5  9 10
```

Comment: Or more generally, `df[] <- lapply(df, gsub, pattern = "[[:punct:]]", replacement = "")`

Comment: You can also use `unlist` instead of `as.matrix`. Not sure which more efficient

Comment: @Ananda But then some columns are having NA as value. How can i remove them?